# extract hex IP from struct addrinfo

Tags: c, tcp, ip

I have populated my structure `struct addrinfo **res` with data:

```
err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res);
```

if I want to print the IP address, I could use

```
addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(res->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
printf("ip address : %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
```

and that would print for example `10.111.1.11`. But I need the IP in hex format, i.e. `0A6F010B`.
I came up with following, which will indeed print the IP in hex format:

```
for (i=0; i<32; i=i+8)
    printf("%02X",(addr.s_addr>>i) % 256) ;
```

But it seems to me that my approach is needlessly complicated. I need two steps (two conversions).  I would like to simplify my code, if possible, and print the hex IP directly from `res->ai_addr->sa_data` (without having to store the data in `addr.s_addr` first).

I know that the data is there in `res->ai_addr->sa_data`. I can print it with:

```
for (i=0; i<14; i++)
    printf("%d", res->ai_addr->sa_data[i]);
printf("\n");
```

and I get following output (which corresponds to `10.111.1.11`):

```
001011111100000000
```

But the format is not as straightforward as in the previous example. For example for `172.25.0.31` I get this output:

```
00-842503100000000
```

## Thus my question:

How can I convert this gibberish into hex IP adress?

Comment: If you want hex, why are you using `%d`, which is decimal?

Comment: [Maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7414943/596781).

Comment: You also got lost among the stars. Your `res` should be a `struct addrinfo *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7414943/596781) and [this description of `sockaddr`](http://www.retran.com/beej/sockaddr_inman.html), you need to do some dynamic type mangling. With the correct types, it might look something like so:

```
struct addrinfo * res;
err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res);

// check that the operation succeeded
assert(err == 0);

// check that the dynamic type is AF_INET
assert(res->ai_addr->sa_family == AF_INET);

// downcast
struct sockaddr_in * p = (struct sockaddr_in *)(res->ai_addr);

// done
printf("Address: %08X (%s)\n", p->sin_addr.s_addr, inet_ntoa(p->sin_addr));
```

---

A more complete example that performs a proper dynamic type selection might look like this:

```
char str[128];

switch (res->ai_addr->sa_family)
{
  case AF_INET:
  {
      struct sockaddr_in * p = (struct sockaddr_in *)(res->ai_addr);
      if (inet_ntop(p->sin_family, &p->sin_addr, str, sizeof str) == NULL)
          fprintf(stderr, "Error in inet_ntop: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      else
          printf("Address: %08X (%s)\n", p->sin_addr.s_addr, str);
      break;
  }
  case AF_INET6:
  {
      struct sockaddr_in6 * p = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)(res->ai_addr);
      if (inet_ntop(p->sin6_family, &p->sin6_addr, str, sizeof str) == NULL)
          fprintf(stderr, "Error in inet_ntop: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      else
          printf("Address: %s\n", str);
      break;
  }
  default:
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unrecogized address family, skipping.\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: but this will print the hex IP in reverse, i.e. `0B016F0A` instead of the correct `0A6F010B`.

Comment: @MartinVegter: That's not reverse. What's reverse is your expectation :-)

Comment: not so much my expectation, as the expectation of my `tftp` server.

Comment: @MartinVegter: I added a convenience function call to help your server.

Comment: that's very nice, but I will still need to "reverse" the hex IP.

Comment: Could you please explain the downcast part?. `p` is just a pointer at `sockaddr_in`. The downcast just casts one type of pointer into another type of pointer. Correct? It does not cast any structure into another structure (i.e. `sockaddr` into `sockaddr_in`)?

Comment: @MartinVegter: Downcasting is only *ever* performed on pointers or references. Actual values are not cast, but *converted*. In the present situation, we have a fixed object, but only a generic pointer to it. We "downcast" to a more specific kind of pointer (to the same object).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at an implementation of `inet_ntoa` [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/net.subproj/inet_ntoa.c):

```
#define UC(b)   (((int)b)&0xff)

char* net_ntoa(struct in_addr in) {
    static char b[18];
    register char *p;
    p = (char *)&in;
    snprintf(b, sizeof(b), "%d.%d.%d.%d", UC(p[0]), UC(p[1]), UC(p[2]), UC(p[3]));
    return (b);
}
```

You can change their implementation to suit your needs simply by swapping in the desired format, i.e. hex:

```
snprintf(b, sizeof(b), "%02X%02X%02X%02X", UC(p[0]), UC(p[1]), UC(p[2]), UC(p[3]));
```

Note that their solution is not thread-safe, because it uses a function-static buffer for the output. To make it thread-safe, change the function to take an output buffer, and require the buffer to have at least nine characters (eight for the hex output plus one for the null terminator.