# Efficient way to store IPv4/IPv6 addresses

Tags: c++, gcc, ipv6, ipv4, int128

I am working on a C/C++ networking project that it should be able to both use the IPv4 and IPv6 networking stacks.
The project works only on Linux.
So, I tried to find an  efficient way to store the IP addresses and differentiate between the protocol families.
The first approach was to have a union:

```
struct ip_addr {
   uint8_t fam; // socket family type
   union {
       struct in_addr ipv4_sin_addr;
       struct in6_addr ipv6_sin_addr;
   } addr;
};
```

The second approach was to define a `typedef std::vector IPAddressNumber`and make the difference after the number of bytes from the vector.

The third approach was to use int128_t/uint128_t or __int128_t from gcc.

For this last case, I would like to know from which version of GCC these types are supported, for which platforms (especially IA-32/IA-64) and also if there are any known bugs. Also, which of the above solutions might be the most convenient one?

Comment: I'm not sure that `int128_t` is needed or suitable for IPv6 addresses. Posix gives other types in its API. For GCC, better use the latest version (GCC 4.9.1 in october 2014) and use C++11 if possible.

Comment: I'd also recommend to use the [`struct sockaddr_in6`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) structure to deal with IPv6 addresses.

Comment: You'll rarely use IP addresses as real numbers (besides they'll need to be provided in network byte order). So again: Using a `uint128_t` for representation of an IPv6 address is probably a **very bad idea**!

Comment: [What should we do with a XY problem question, where X can be answered?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275182/what-should-we-do-with-a-xy-problem-question-where-x-can-be-answered)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thank you for your quick answers! I am afraid I haven't given enough details about the project I am working at. I will edit my post and add more information.

Comment: @AziNuAmChef What actually makes you believe, that a 128 bit integer would be a better representation than `struct sockaddr_in6`? Can you elaborate on this, to improve your question please?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I have just finished editing.

Comment: `typedef std::vector<unsigned char> IPAddressNumber` I'd prefer `typedef std::array<unsigned char,16> IPAddressNumber`.

Comment: @AziNuAmChef I have added some more information to my answer.

Comment: `struct sockaddr_storage` can be used for family agnostic storage, it is convenient, by definition not bit-frugal.

Answer (score 10):

*As stated in the [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532162/1413395) 128 bit integer support is available since GCC 4.6.4.*

Your problem isn't 128 bit integer support, but ***how to represent an IPv6 address*** correctly.
The correct answer for this, is to use the `struct` definitions available from the [socket API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html).

These are available and standardized for various operating system implementations of the IPv6 stack.
Also you don't need to worry about *efficiency* using these. Alignment packing will do its work  properly, and you don't have to care about endianess vs network byte order issues of the actual representation.

---

As for your edits:

**You don't have to reinvent the wheel!** There are already appropriate `struct` definitions available respecting the `AF_xxx` family type correctly.

Check these resources for more detailed explanations:

- [**Understanding struct sockaddr**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414943/understanding-struct-sockaddr).
- [`sys/socket.h` - main sockets header](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html)
- [`netinet/in.h` - Internet address family](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netinet/in.h.html)

We have an `IpAddr` class in production, that uses the opaque `sockaddr_in*` and `sockaddr_in6*` pointers to encapsulate either an IPv4 or IPv6 address based on a `sockaddr*` pointer, and `reinterpret_cast<>` based on the `sa_family` member of the structure.

Comment: I actually saw an open source project (chromium) that uses a similar representation with the one mentioned by you: it uses a struct called SockaddrStorage [1] and a class named IPEndPoint that works with this struct.
The problem with this struct is that it is useful when you have also a port or you intend to create a socket(eg: bind , connect calls) and not just for storing the ip.
[1]
http://goo.gl/hSyW8o

Comment: I need an internal way to store the ip after converting it from a string representation(ie: from a flag or an environment variable).
I find more useful the representation with struct ip_addr because it is more convenient for calls like inet_ntop/inet_pton
It is not possible to use sockaddr (alone and not as a pointer) because the sa_data  field is not big enough to store an IPv6 address.

Comment: @evelina _"I need an internal way to store the ip after converting it from a string representation(ie: from a flag or an environment variable)."_ Well, I don't understand, what you're actually bothering about _efficiency_. The mentioned structures will well represent the IP protocol dependent types.

Comment: Nice answer. Using it.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576217/is-there-any-way-to-do-128-bit-ints-on-gcc-4-4) `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` were introduced somewhere around version 4.2. And according to GCC's documentation `__int128` and its unsigned counterpart `unsigned __int128` are supported since [GCC 4.6.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html#_005f_005fint128).

Note that an unportable 128-bit integer is definitely **not** the appropriate type to save and work with IPv6 addresses. As mentioned in the comments there are special data structures for this, like [`sockaddr_in6`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html).

Comment: Well, this answers for the support of 128 bit integers, but I'm afraid that's not the right data type for representation of IPv6 addresses :-/ ...

Comment: I've put my own answer now, as having been advised so. But yes pointing out the Y problem improves your answer.

Comment: @Loopunroller Thank you for the answers! I have added more info about my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This code is from nginx. It's the same as 1st answer.
I don't think it's a good idea to use pointer sockaddr_in* .

```
typedef union {
    struct sockaddr           sockaddr;
    struct sockaddr_in        sockaddr_in;
#if (NGX_HAVE_INET6)
    struct sockaddr_in6       sockaddr_in6;
#endif
#if (NGX_HAVE_UNIX_DOMAIN)
    struct sockaddr_un        sockaddr_un;
#endif
} ngx_sockaddr_t;
```

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/912fb44e25c6ab2598e36b4544c709b871251b2e/src/core/ngx_inet.h#L44