# What's the best way to store a set of IPv6 addresses?

Tags: c++, data-structures, ipv6, endianness

I'm modernizing a legacy application that stores IPv4 addresses in a fixed-size array of unsigned longs. The addresses are stored in host byte order. That is, it is `ntohl()`'d when coming from the socket API and `htonl()`'d when going to the socket API.

Now in order to support IPv6 as well, I'm wondering what to do with this array. 
Whether I should store the string representation, and make it an array of `char[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]` or even a `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::set<std::string>` to support more addresses.

Or, I could store the `in6_addr` structs, which is probably way more efficient to work with than a `std::string`, but then I'm wondering how does network and host byte order apply here?

Comment: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531531/efficient-way-to-store-ipv4-ipv6-addresses

Comment: `in6_addr` should be definitely the better choice vs `std::string`.  "how does network and host byte order apply here?", well you cannot longer use simple `long` values to store IPv6 addresses.

Comment: so just use struct in6_addr and don't try to convert it into a 128bit integer. Seems fair.

Comment: @Philipp Yes. You should provide a class for encapsulation of the API functions, as I recommended in the asnwer to the linked question above.

Comment: What are you doing with the stored addresses?

Answer (score 0):

in6_addr does require the address to be in network byte order. in6_addr internally stores ipv6 address as a union of 16 chars, 8 shorts, 4 ints.