# Can double be used to store and safely retrieve 128 bit IPv6?

Tags: c++, double, ipv6

As we know `double` can store number from `±4.94065645841246544e-324` to `±1.79769313486231570e+308`. Can we store 128 bits value like IPv6 in `double` and retrieve as it is? For example, to store IPv4 we can use a 32 bit integer and store them as 8 bits partition. And we can retrieve them by using bit masking.

There is no standard container to store 128 bit in any language AFAIK. I know `double` can store 64 bits safely without any precision error but is there any hack?

Comment: you cannot store 128 bits of information in less than 128 bits, double usually has 64 bits, so no

Comment: Check what the `sizeof(double)` is.  If it is not `16` then no.

Comment: No, that won't work. IPv6 addresses are 128-bit integers which have far too many significant digits. Floating point numbers don't have enough significant digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically you could, if `sizeof(double) * CHAR_BITS` ≥ 128 (it's 64bits on my machine), but why would you do that? Instead of reinventing the wheel use `sockaddr_in6`, or, if you must, an array of `uint8_t` or a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Related answer: [Efficient way to store IPv4/IPv6 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531531/efficient-way-to-store-ipv4-ipv6-addresses)

Answer (score 3):

I would be reluctant to use a double because [its size is unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25524458/783510).

If you need a 128 bit integer, I would recommend to use non-standard types as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1188939/783510).