# Converting IPv6 addresses to 64-bit double

Tags: php, c++, floating-point, ipv6

IPv6 addresses are 128-bit unsigned integers under the hood, so their range of 
 values is [0,  3.40 × 10^38]

> A 128-bit register can store 2^128 (over 3.40 × 10^38) different values. The range of integer values that can be stored in 128 bits depends on the integer representation used. With the two most common representations, the range is 0 through 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,455 (2^128 − 1) for representation as an (unsigned) binary number, 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit

A double-precision float variable in whatever language, though, can be as high as ±1.79769313486231570e+308 , so it definitely can assume all the values a 128-bit int can, and even more.

I'm sure there is a ready-to-use function/library/piece of code to convert from IPv6 => double.
Can anyone post code to do that, or a link?

Thanks

Preferably PHP, but you can post code in other languages and i will translate to PHP.

P.S.
i've read this related question [Can double be used to store and safely retrieve 128 bit IPv6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050286/can-double-be-used-to-store-and-safely-retrieve-128-bit-ipv6?noredirect=1&lq=1) but IMO the answers were wrong, because you **don't need** a variable with the same bits as the IPv6 address (128-bit).
You just need it to be able to assume all the possible values an IPv6 can have.
As i said above, a double can represent al the possible values of an 128-bit int and even more, despite it being just 64-bit.

How's that possible?

This is the magic of floating-point registers. 
They are more CPU-intensive to do calculations with compared to integer ones, but are more powerful.

EDIT: Why do i need this conversion:
i have a MySQL table with IPv6 addresses defined as DECIMAL(39), which is a 39-digit int. I need to query that table by visitor's address if it is IPv6.

Comment: `double` can't store every unique values in the range. It's limited to a certain number of significant digits. If it fits in 64 bit it can **at most** represent `2^64` different possible values (otherwise at least 2 values would share the same bit representation at which point they cease to be distinct) which is far less than `2^128`.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use [`inet_pton`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php), it doesn't return a double, but is that important?

Comment: Sounds like an xy question. Why do you think you need to convert ip's to doubles?

Comment: "double can represent al the possible values of an 128-bit int and even more, despite it being just 64-bit." no way. Forget all details about doubles and integers, then in 128-bit there are 2^128 different values in 64-bit there are only 2^64. Your question is based on a false premise, and it is rather unclear why you want a double in the first place

Comment: @Nigel and fstam Yes i need this conversion because i have a MySQL table with IPv6 addresses defined as DECIMAL(39), which is a 39-digit int. I need to query that table by visitor's address if it is IPv6.

Comment: i think you should read up on information science *basics* before working any more in programming. please.

Comment: IP addresses are unisigned binary integers (whole numbers). That is how they are used by the networks, stored and used as 128-bit integers. The 128-bit integers are used in operations, such as bitwise AND and OR. Other representations cannot be properly manipulated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> A double-precision float variable in whatever language, though, can be as high as ±1.79769313486231570e+308 , so it definitely can assume all the values a 128-bit int can, and even more.

This assumption is wrong. A double-precision float variable can **not** assume all the values a 128-bit int can.

This is because the floating point type in computer science has limited precision. Once you get to numbers greater than 2^52, you can no longer represent individual integers in that range. You're limited to 2^52, 2^52+2, 2^52+4, 2^52+6, ... until you reach 2^53, at which point you lose more precision, only representing values 2^53, 2^53+4, 2^53+8, 2^53+12, ...

So if, say, your IPv6 address is 2^52+1, a `double` would be incapable of representing it.

So no, it is not possible to represent the whole range of IPv6 addresses in the space defined by a `double`, 64-bit floating point value.

See [Is Floating Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for a more detailed breakdown on how Floating Point math works in computers.

---

Part of your issue appears to be some confusion between types. A `DECIMAL` type in computer science is not the same kind of type as a `double` type. `decimal` types are usually some kind of BigNum implementation. They probably *can* store an entire IPv6 address, but it's not going to do it in only 64-bits. It'll use whatever quantity of bits is required by the database implementation (probably more than 128 bits, since `decimal` is usually designed to handle fixed-point math).

If you need to save an IPv6 address in a database, you *might* be able to get away with it with a `decimal(39)` type, but to be safe, you should be using one of these instead:

- An explicitly sized 128-bit integer field
- A 16-byte `VARCHAR` (or some other string-like field) that saves 8 bits per character
- A 64-byte `VARCHAR` field that saves the IP Address in a Hexadecimal-encoded string (like how they are commonly represented).
- A 22-byte `VARCHAR` field that saves the IP Address in a BASE64-encoded string

Comment: Note: a 39-digit decimal number would require 130 bits to store as an integer, but as mysql does something funky for DECIMAL it's between 4 and 5 bytes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric

Comment: Also the 16-byte representation should be stored as BIN or VARBIN to avoid being munged by encoding snafus.

Comment: @Sammitch The documentation you quoted suggests it would take 18 bytes to store a `DECIMAL(39)` number (39/9 == 4, 4*4 == 16, leftover is 3 digits requiring 2 additional bytes).